# Identify pieces included in an app from 1990ish Acorn A3000 called Maestro

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I had an Acorn A3000 when I was younger and it has a music writing application called Maestro with a few pieces of music pre-programmed into it.

This is one that I have remembered ever since but I don’t know if it’s a real piece of music or just one written for this application.

The music starts at about 1:24 in this video called [Acorn Archimedes : Arthur OS : Welcome Disc : Maestro (Simulated monitor)](https://youtu.be/KawbGvQydkg?t=84).

Comment: @AlvaroFuentes oh excellent! I didn't even know there was a user manual! Thanks for the link! Looks like you're probably right that they're original compositions. I think the version I had was a later version of Maestro with the same tune but it was called "Fugue" in that version. Not Tune 1. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [user's manual](http://chrisacorns.computinghistory.org.uk/docs/Acorn/Manuals/Acorn_ArchimedesWGA.pdf) identifies the two example scores only as tune1 and tune2 (see pages 40 and 76). They are likely original compositions.